# Проблема с добавлением символов в массив

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, операторы

Имеется функция:

```
int generateShips(char field[24][24], int i, int j, int n) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    j = rand() % 13 + 2;
    i = rand() % 19 + 2;

    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        field[i][j + k] = '#';
        field[i + 1][j + k] = '#';              //Четырёхпалубник
    }


    /*Производим итерацию 2 раза, т.к 3-палубных корабля 2*/
    for (int m = 0; m < 2; m++) {
        /*Генерируем случайное число. Проверяем, чтобы необходимая область для корабля не была занята.
        Именно в таких пределах, ибо поле 22х22, где первые 2 и последние 2 элемента границы.
        Изначально предполагается, что "корабли" будут создаваться в горизонтальном положении.*/
        while (true) {
            j = rand() % 15 + 2;        
            i = rand() % 19 + 2;
            if (field[i][j] == field[i][j + 1] == field[i][j + 2] ==field[i+1][j] == field[i+1][j + 1] == field[i+1][j + 2] == ' '&&i%2==0&&j%2==0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
            field[i][j + k] = '#';
            field[i+1][j + k] = '#';        
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Задача - создать корабли для игры «морской бой» (путём добавления символа '#' в массив). В первой части функции всё работает нормально (добавление четырехпалубного корабля), а при добавлении трехпалубных кораблей имеется проблема: при выводе массива в нём ничего не оказывается из добавленных во второй части функции символов. В чём проблема?

Comment: Я так понимаю, "четырехпалубник" добавляется нормально, а "трехпалубники" уже не очень?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, ошибка в этих строках:

```
if (field[i][j] == field[i][j + 1] == field[i][j + 2] ==field[i+1][j] == field[i+1][j + 1] == field[i+1][j + 2] == ' ') {
    break;
}
```

Не могу объяснить, почему, но знаю по опыту, что так не стоит сравнивать.
Попробуйте сделать так:

```
1) Объявите функцию:

bool f(vector<char> a) {
    for(int i = 1; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        if(a[i] != a[i - 1]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return a[0] == ' ';
}

2) Поменяйте проблемные строки на: 

if(f({field[i][j], field[i][j + 1], field[i][j + 2], field[i + 1][j], ld[i + 1][j + 1], field[i + 1][j + 2]}) && (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0)) {
    break;
}
```

Ну, или же можно обойтись простым, но так больше кода:

```
if (field[i][j] == field[i][j + 1] && field[i][j] == field[i][j + 2] && field[i][j] == field[i + 1][j] && field[i][j] == field[i + 1][j + 1] && field[i][j] == field[i + 1][j + 2] && field[i][j] == ' ' && (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0)) {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (field[i][j]       == field[i][j + 1]   == 
    field[i][j + 2]   == field[i+1][j]     == 
    field[i+1][j + 1] == field[i+1][j + 2] == ' ' && 
    i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0)
```

Ошибка в этих строках действительно имеется и вот какая. Вызывается первый оператор `==` для `field[i][j] == field[i][j + 1]`. Что будет результатом его работы? `true/false`, или можно считать, что `false` это `0`, а `true` это число, отличное от нуля. А дальше оно, это число, показывающее истинность, сравнивается посредством второго оператора `==` с `field[i][j + 2]`. Полагаю, Вы не хотели такого поведения. В дополнение, хочу обратить Ваше внимание на работу операторов `||` и `&&`:

```
if(flag && some_condition()) {...}

if(flag || some_condition()) {...}
```

В первом `if` условие `some_condition()` не вычисляется, если `flag` суть `false`, во втором случае - если `flag` суть `true`. Применение: например, если в первой части условного выражения Вы проверяете указатель на равенство `nullptr`, и если и только если это не так, то происходит вычисление второй (более правой) части условного выражения, в которой этот указатель, к примеру, разыменовывается, что определенно было бы неправильно будь он нулевым указателем.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (a == b == 0) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вот минимальный пример (выше), выведено будет `true`, хотя, полагаю, Вы ожидали `false`;)

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));

    const int N = 24;

    char field[N][N];

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for(j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            field[i][j] = '-';

    i = rand() % 19 + 2;
    j = rand() % 13 + 2;

    for (k = 0; k < 4; ++k) // 4 - четырехпалубник ?
    {
        field[i][j + k] = '#';
        //field[i + 1][j + k] = '#'; // зачем это ?
    }

    for (int m = 0; m < 2; ++m) 
    {
        while (true) 
        {
            i = rand() % 19 + 2;
            j = rand() % 15 + 2;        

            if (field[i][j] == field[i][j + 1] && 
                field[i][j] == field[i][j + 2] && 
                field[i][j] == field[i + 1][j] && 
                field[i][j] == field[i + 1][j + 1] && 
                field[i][j] == field[i + 1][j + 2] && 
                field[i][j] == '-' && 
                (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0)) break;
        }

        for (k = 0; k < 3; ++k) // было 6, почему, ведь трехпалубник ?
        {
            field[i][j + k] = '#';
            //field[i+1][j + k] = '#'; // зачем это ?        
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            std::cout << field[i][j];
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Вот такой вариант Вашего кода вполне работоспособен. Еще обратите внимание, я отметил комментариями некоторые строки, поскольку не понял до конца Вашу модель морского боя. В моем представлении палуба - одна клетка. А если у Вас палуба - это квадрат из четырех символов `#`, то в первом цикле (для четырехпалубника) надо `8` поставить, а не `4` (у Вас).

Comment: Jenssen, да, тут перепутал, спасибо. А заменяю на # для обозначение корабля